# how to change background color and text color in jquery

Tags: jquery

How do I change my paragraph section background color and text color also? I used this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("p:first-child").css("color", "red");
    $(this).css("background", "black");
});
```

Now I see my div text color change into red but background color does not change.

Answer (score 3):

Why didn't you write like this?

```
$("p:first-child").css({"color":"red","background-color":"black"});
```

Pass properties as an object to `.css()`

Your code did not work, since `$(this)` inside document ready will point document only not the other elements.

Comment: but why didnt it work with `$(this)`?

Comment: Thanks Rajaprabhu your suggestion is very helpful for me.

Comment: @AmmarCSE `$(this)` will point to the document at that context.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, I know. I want you to include it in your answer so it will be more complete

Comment: @AmmarCSE You could have edited it on behalf of me. But not sure what kind of prestige issue you went with :\ Will update it now.

Comment: there we go, thats better. @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, its not a prestige issue, I just wanted to see it in the answer before I upvote, thanks ;)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, some users will get annoyed if others edit their answers, thats one reason why I didnt do it myself

Comment: @AmmarCSE :) What's in that? This platform is actually for sharing knowledge.  No matter who edits our post. :)

Answer (score 0):

You gotta use `background-color` instead of `background`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("p:first-child").css("color", "red");
        $(this).css("background-color", "black"); // <----
});
```

Also - this code is currently setting the background-color on the `document`, which is probably not what you want. The code to change the color and background-color of the paragraph itself should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("p:first-child").css("color", "red").css("background-color", "black");
});
```

Comment: Mr. Loyalar you are right but why i add css 2 time while conversely the same work can be 1 css like this:    $("p:first-child").css({"color":"red","background-color":"black"});

Comment: can i tacking to another question